# Can site on subdomain compete with another site on domain?

Tags: seo, google, subdomain

Can my site on subdomain.mydomain.com compete with another (not my) site on yourdomain.com from the SEO point of view?

Comment: The answer is no. A good example is site that host on blogspot.com , wordpress.

Comment: By "compete with" do you mean "rank at the the same time, similar to the way that a competitor might", or do you mean "rank instead of"?

Answer (score 1):

I'm going to answer based on logical assumptions.

The word you are looking for here is **rank**.

Generally, search engines like to index websites with high quality content that people constantly want to see (based on their query) at the top and on the first page. Some search engines (like google) may place websites that directly sponsor them relevant to the user's query above other websites and the links to such sites will have the label "ad" or something similar to indicate that its an advertisement.

So if you want to look at it competition style with examples, then I'll explain:

Say subdomain.mydomain.com has an entire website that consists only of one picture and only one sentence about apples. and yourdomain.com consists of 10 well-written paragraphs about apples.

If a user searches for apples, then generally yourdomain.com will likely appear before subdomain.mydomain.com because it has more text that search engines analyzed and believed to match the user's query. Now yourdomain.com will definitely appear before subdomain.mydomain.com if many different users keep accessing yourdomain.com in the results because it is hinting to the search engine that users would visit yourdomain.com more times than subdomain.mydomain.com which might suggest to the search engine that it has better content.

It's all the matter of making the content for the user, not for the bot, and the easiest way to lose "ranking" (position in search results) is to make the worst site ever.

You might want to see http://www.webpagesthatsuck.com/ for examples of websites made several years ago that just aren't meant for users.